# Writing to Firestore using Pub/Sub and Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm currently using Dataflow to receive the data from MQTT server through a pub/sub topic and push it to BigQuery using python.
This is working as expected and now I want to do the same to write on Firestore specific collection (based on the data received). Currently doing this with Cloud Function, but for scalability and concurrency writing in Firestore, I want a more scalable and error prune method.
I couldn't find a connector for Firestore in python and the one in Java doesn't support Streaming, just batch processing.

Before diving into the code, I would like to have some views from the experts as this is an IoT application which can have bursts of data then need to be updated on Firestore, used for Georeference map view:

1. Is there any Apache beam connector to Firestore supporting Stream in python?
2. Can I implement dataflow job with 10-15s window to overcome the "maximum sustained write rate to a document is 1 per second"?
3. Is this a good approach and more scalable then Cloud Functions v2 for streaming data into Firestore?
4. Is it possible to implement batch writes in a dataflow job?
5. Since the Collection of writing is dependent on the data received, is this possible to implement? Something like the following:

   ```
   data coming: "networkId, nodeId, long, lat, date, ..."
   Check collection: /Customers/{customerX}/("networkId" inside document pointing to siteId)
   Dataflow picks "CustomerX" name, and writes in Collection Firestore: /SiteId/Nodes/{"nodeId"}
   ```

We are currently using with few updates eery minute, so the solution currently works as expected. We are growing and expect the numbers to go high quickly so we need to find a more scalable way that overcomes some of the already known limitations.
Your help and guidance is much appreciated.

Comment: For the Filiestore IO question, based on https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/connectors/, the answer is no for Python. And no streaming support.